# v-model on nested v-for always change all data

Tags: arrays, nested, nuxt.js, v-for

i have problem with nested loop in nuxtjs (which is v-for)
my nuxt version is "^2.15.8"

[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyjzU.png)

simply look like this

```
objPerspective:{ Customer: [ { target: [{},{},{},{}] }, { target: [{},{},{},{}] } ], Finance: [ { target: [{},{},{},{}] }, { target: [{},{},{},{}] } ], Learn: [ { target: [{},{},{},{}] }, { target: [{},{},{},{}] } ], Business: [ { target: [{},{},{},{}] }, { target: [{},{},{},{}] } ], }
```

[all data have same value like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oidxf.png)

and here the problem:

When i change the input target_value for example in

```
objPerspective.Finance[0].target[0].target_value
```

the data in same index target.target_value but in another object like customer, internal, and learn for example

```
objPerspective.Learn[0].target[0].target_value
```

changed with same value

and for another example when i change

```
objPerspective.Customer[0].target[0].target_value
```

and it do same thing, change learn etc target_value

and i have one function to push new object data to array finance, learn etc  with same data so the array can have 2 object

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic8aZ.png)

and when i change the target_value in new array that i already push for example :

```
objPerspective.Finance[1].target[0].target_value
```

The value works properly and do not change the target_value for example:

```
objPerspective['Learn And Growth'][1].target[0].target_value
```

code :

```
 <div  class="p-[20px] overflow-x-auto">
       // start of v-for objPerspective 
        <table v-for="(arrObjPerspective, perspectiveName, idTable) in objPerspective" :key="idTable" class="table-fixed w-full">
          <thead class="bg-[#F9FAFF] font-thin text-left text-[14px]">
            <tr>
              <th :rowspan="2" class="border border-1 border-[#E1E5F1] font-semibold w-[150px]">
                <div class="pl-[10px]">Perspektif</div>
              </th>
              <th :rowspan="2" class="border border-1 border-[#E1E5F1] font-semibold w-[350px]">
                <div class="pl-[10px]">Key Result Area</div>
              </th>
              <th :rowspan="2" class="border border-1 border-[#E1E5F1] font-semibold w-[450px]">
                <div class="pl-[10px]">Key Performance Indicator</div>
              </th>

              <th :rowspan="2" class="border border-1 border-[#E1E5F1] font-semibold w-[170px]">
                <div class="pl-[10px]">Weight</div>
              </th>
              <th :colspan="count" class="border border-1 border-[#E1E5F1] font-semibold w-[1800px]">
                <div class="pl-[10px]">Target</div>
              </th>
              <th :rowspan="2" class="border border-1 border-[#E1E5F1] font-semibold w-[150px]">
                <div class="pl-[10px]">Action</div>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th v-for="n in count" class="border border-1 border-[#E1E5F1] font-semibold">
                <div v-if="n < count" class="pl-[10px]">{{ targetConfigName }}{{ n }}</div>
                <div v-if="n === count" class="pl-[10px]">{{ new Date().getFullYear() }}</div>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="text-[13px]">
            <tr>
              <td :rowspan="objPerspective[perspectiveName].length + 2"
                class="bg-[#F9FAFF] border border-[#E1E5F1] font-semibold">
                {{ perspectiveName }}
              </td>
            </tr>

            //start of v-for arrObjPerspective
            <tr v-for="(item, idVal) in arrObjPerspective" :key="idVal" class="border border-1 border-[#E1E5F1]">
              <td class="border border-1 border-[#E1E5F1]">
                <div class="flex justify-center py-[10px]">
                  <input @change="checkChange(perspectiveName, i)" v-model="item.key_result_area_name" type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter Key Result Area"
                    class="placeholder:text-[13px] outline outline-1 outline-[#ECECEC] w-11/12 py-[5px] px-[10px] rounded" />
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="flex justify-center py-[10px] gap-[10px] w-full">
                  <select v-model="item.unit"
                    class="outline outline-1 outline-[#ECECEC] px-[5px] font-bold text-[13px] rounded" name="" id="">
                    <option value="%">%</option>
                    <option value="#">#</option>
                  </select>
                  <input @change="checkChange(perspectiveName, i)" v-model="item.kpi_name" type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter Key Perfomance Indicator"
                    class="placeholder:text-[13px] outline outline-1 outline-[#ECECEC] w-9/12 py-[5px] px-[10px] rounded" />
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="border border-1 border-[#E1E5F1]">
                <div class="flex justify-center py-[10px]">
                  <input @change="checkChange(perspectiveName, i)" v-model="item.weight" type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter Weight"
                    class="placeholder:text-[13px] w-9/12 outline outline-1 outline-[#ECECEC] py-[5px] px-[10px] rounded-l" />
                  <div
                    class="text-center font-bold bg-[#F5F6FA] outline outline-1 outline-[#ECECEC] w-2/12 px-[10px] rounded-r grid content-center">
                    %
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              // HERE THE PROBLEM
              //start of v-for item.target
              <td v-for="(target, indexTarget) in item.target" :key="indexTarget" class="border border-1 border-[#E1E5F1]">
                <div class="flex justify-center py-[10px]">
//HERE THE PROBLEM V-MODEL
                  <input v-model="target.target_value" :placeholder="`Enter ${target.order}`"
                    class="placeholder:text-[10px] outline outline-1 outline-[#ECECEC] w-8/12 py-[5px] px-[7px] rounded"
                    type="text" />
                </div>
              </td>
              //end of v-for item.target
            </tr>
            //end of v-for arrObjPerspective

            <tr>
              <td :colspan="count + 5" class="border border-1 border-[#E1E5F1] py-[15px]">
                <div class="flex justify-center">
                  <button @click="pushNew(perspectiveName)"
                    class="font-bold outline outline-1 outline-[#DD292F] text-[#DD292F] py-[5px] px-[20px] rounded">
                    Add a row
                  </button>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        //end of v-for objPerspective
      </div>
```

pushNew()

```
pushNew(perspectiveName) {
      let target = this.getArrTemp()
      this.objPerspective[perspectiveName].push({
        kpi_name: "",
        key_result_area_name: "",
        weight: "",
        unit: "%",
        target,
        isItFilled: false,
        allTotalWeight: 0
      })
      // force update, because v-for v-for="(item, i) in val" not reactive
      this.$forceUpdate()
    }
```

i have already try to change the v-model like this v-model="objPerspective[perspectiveName][idVal]['target'][indexTarget]['target_value']" and it still not work properly